# duplicity - what does 'full backup' mean?

Tags: debian, backup, duplicity

I'm thinking about using duplicity to have my offsite backup encrypted. Until now, I'm using a script which runs rsync, pretty straightforward. I've done some reading on duplicity, but I can't seem to find the answer to this question:

When doing a new full backup, does duplicity transfer every file again? Or does it combine the last full backup (on the remote server) and the incremental backups there to create new files, i.e. the new full backup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When doing a new full backup, does duplicity transfer every file again?

yes.

> Or does it combine the last full backup (on the remote server) and the incremental backups there to create new files, i.e. the new full backup?

no. duplicity treats backends as dumb storage. that's why it works with so many different types of backend.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know if any program could do what I asked?